# Inplace modification of S4 object: pro and cons

Tags: r, r-s4

Using `eval.parent` and `substitute`, it is possible to write a function that modifies its argument; for example:

```
> setClass("foo", representation(bar="vector"))
> f <- function(x) eval.parent(substitute(x@bar <- x@bar+1))
> a <- new("foo", bar = 0)
> a
An object of class "foo"
Slot "bar":
[1] 0

> f(a)
> a
An object of class "foo"
Slot "bar":
[1] 1
```

However most of the time people prefer to write it as follows:

```
> g <- function(x) { x@bar <- x@bar + 1; x }
> a <- g(a)
> a
An object of class "foo"
Slot "bar":
[1] 2
```

Are there any problems with the first method?

Would it be ok to use it in a package submitted to the CRAN (there’s no warning with `check --as-cran`, so the answer should be yes)?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: `f(a)` actually returns it's last line -- the rhs of the assignment. `f(new("foo", bar=0))` fails. `h = function(x) f(x); h(a)` does not modify `a`, but `i = function(x) g(x); i(a)` returns a modified `a`. It's not always obvious were the appropriate frame of evaluation is, e.g., when a method implements a generic but with a different signature, the method has a `.local` function nested in the main code.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I did already found out that using `f(x)` inside of a function might be unhandy. But the impossibility to do `f( new("foo", bar = 0) )` or `f( function_creating_a_foo( ... ) )` is, in my opinion, a much more serious problem. This is enough to answer my question (even though I would be interested by knowing the CRAN position on the subject), if you want to turn your comment in an answer I’ll be glad to accept it.